# Conditional and density probability (normal distribution)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function, marginal-distribution, conditional

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose that $\mu\sim N(1,4)$ and $Y|\mu\sim N(\mu,1)$. Show that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}Y \\ \mu \end{bmatrix} \sim N\bigg(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}5 & 4 \\ 4 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\bigg) .$$

First, I used the fact that:
$$f_{Y,\mu}(Y,\mu)=f_{Y|\mu}(Y|\mu)f_\mu(\mu).$$

Then, I can easily write out $f_\mu(\mu)$ as:
$$f_\mu(\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{4}}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{(\mu-1)^2}{8}\bigg\}.$$

Now what I do not know is how to write out the conditional density $f_{Y|\mu}(Y|\mu)$ appropriately.
I tried to write it as:

$$f_{Y|\mu}(Y|\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\bigg\{-\frac{(Y-\mu)^2}{2}\bigg\},$$

but, by this, I could not find the right result.

Does any of you have an idea on what is the right way to write out a conditional density? Are my other statements correct?

Thank you in advance for your time!